# Ubuntu 22.04 boots into a purple/gray screen

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi

I am running on an HP Spectre-x360-convertible. Does anyone have a solution for booting into ubuntu without getting this purple/gray screen?

**The Problem**
: The pc starts booting up and loads the grub2 menu. I select Ubuntu and it loads a flickering purple screen.

[Ubuntu screen after booting. The screen changes between purple and gray](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6Xx5.jpg)

**Work Around**
: I found a way around it by booting into bios instead of grub2.

1. [Once in bios I select F9](https://i.stack.imgur.com/460Hg.jpg)
2. [Select ubuntu and it boots correctly and everything loads normally with no issues](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVCMP.jpg)

Comment: Are you saying that the computer never completes the boot process without your work-around?  If that is not the case and if it is just the flickering screen during boot-up, you might find that installing and using grub-customizer to load your own choice of image might be a solution.

Comment: @ve3oat Yes, the computer never completes the boot process without my workaround.

Comment: That *is* strange, and I am sorry that I can't offer a solution.  I hope that someone else here knows more.

Comment: I had exactly the same issue... (I was running 21.10 perfectly but was forced to upgrade as support ended...) I didn't know about your workaround, what kind of worked for me is completely disabling the graphics drivers, I can now boot normally. But I have a number of other graphics-related issues which I suppose are a result of this. So if anyone has a better solution that would be amazing!

Comment: Please open F10 (UEFI settings) > Boot menu. In OS selection make sure the same entry you choose with the Boot override menu (F9) is set to as first priority. Very likely it's set with a old non-working entry.