# Kubuntu/Ubuntu/Fedora Stuck at install on HP Spectre x360 Meteor Lake Core Ultra 155H Laptop dual boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, kernel, kubuntu, uefi

I am a beginner at linux and trying to install it on a HP Spectre X360 laptop with Meteor Lake Core Ultra 155H with dual boot on a single 2TB NVME disk.
I am creating a separate /root partition, but no separate /boot partition since it's a UEFI FS and I believe the grub bootloader will be installed in Windows UEFI partition?

I tried Ubuntu 20.04/22.04/23.10, Fedora 39/38 and Kubuntu 23.04/23.10.

I have turned off Secure Boot, power on lid, hibernation etc from windows 11.
The only Ubuntu I was successful in installing is Ubuntu 20.04 with kernel 5.15 and then upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04 or 23.10 through `sudo do-release-upgrade`, staying on the same kernel. Caveat is the touchpad, WiFi, screen brightness adjustment, Bluetooth etc nothing works. I downloaded the latest Linux firmware to install the drivers, but that didn't help.
It was BE200 Wifi7 chip and `dmesg | grep iwlwifi` does show the driver.
I use a USB C 2.5G Ethernet through which I can use internet and upgrade.
I was able to make WiFi once by bringing the link up (network unclaimed status right now).

The moment I upgrade the kernel to get the right drivers for all the peripherals, I get a kernel panic error or timed out waiting for device/dependency failed for multiple file systems including `/boot/efi`.
If not these, then I am stuck at Hub sensors for all night. Fedora 39/38 doesn't even show the logo as soon as I select try Fedora or install Fedora.
I tried everything suggested so far over the internet (nomodeset, noacpi), balena installer, dd, on 3 different USB drives.

Nothing has worked. Currently trying to install Kubuntu 23.10 and stuck on sensor hub id.
Looking for help as I don't want to be a windows user and don't wish to use a VM. I was able to install Ubuntu 23.10 using VirtualBox, but I wish to have a dual boot system.

There is no legacy UEFI option in the boot menu.

Kubuntu stuck here all day:

[image: Kubuntu stuck here all day]

Dependency error when kernel updated to anything above 6.1 in Ubuntu 22.04:

[image: Dependency error when kernel updated to anything above 6.1 in Ubuntu 22.04]

Mutex Error in Ubuntu kernel 6.5:

[image: Mutex Error in Ubuntu kernel 6.5]

ACPI Bios error before every boot:

[image: ACPI Bios error before every boot]

Mutex Error when USB C Ethernet is connected:

[image: Mutex Error when USB C Ethernet is connected]

Update:
Yesterday I installed 20.04 and updated it to 22.04 LTS Desktop version with kernel 5.15. I then updated the kernel to 5.19, which gives me the main desktop screen, but like 5.15, no interfaces are working except the usb c connected realtek 2.5G ethernet controller to connect to internet.
I then installed kernel 6.1.76 & 6.2. I compiled kernel 6.1.76 and used mainline repository for installing 6.2.
Both got stuck at this place:
[6.1.76 & 6.2 stuck here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LprBN.jpg)

Comment: What happens if you try putting `acpi=off` on the kernel command line? You can edit `/etc/default/grub` and append it to the space-separated values on the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=` line, then do `sudo update-grub`. If it doesn't boot that far, then you can press <kbd>e</kbd> at the GRUB menu , then add it at the end of the "linux" line

Comment: Please be precise with details; you mention creating a separate "*/root*" partition, which makes no sense given `/root` is a directory because it's usually KB to MB only in size; or did you mean the `/` or *root* partition (`/` and `/root` are different).  The `/boot` is likewise a directory and not the ESP or EFI System Partition which is again different (it's mounted at the /boot/efi; but *mounts* aren't partitions). Ubuntu 23.10 is *vague* as Server & Desktops use different installers; and two installers exist if you're talking about Ubuntu 23.10 Desktop, and we don't know which you tried.

Comment: FYI:  If you had success using the HWE kernel stack for 20.04 (ie. 5.15 kernel), that is the GA kernel stack for Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, so why not use (or at least try) an ISO with 22.04 that includes the GA kernel stack. Ubuntu has many ISO choices & not just a single ISO per release....   Five kernels (5.4, 5.8, 5.11, 5.13, 5.15) exist on 20.04 ISOs, so far there are 5.15, 5.19, 6.2 & 6.5 on 22.04, so providing clear details of the ISO used is more precise than just a release.  As a newbie you won't know this; so outline as clear as you can what you tried & please include Server/Desktop etc.

Comment: FYI: Ubuntu 23.10 is available with the `subiquity` installer (Server), the `ubiquity` installer (Desktop) & `ubuntu-desktop-installer` (Desktop).. which did you try?? You mention problems with 23.10 only, but not which you tried, or did you try all three installers. A *flavor* also uses `calamares` but you only mention Ubuntu. If your issue is the install itself, telling which installer/ISO you tried is rather essential.  I'm unsure what you mean by "*no legacy uEFI option*" but Ubuntu Desktop & *flavors* will install to legacy/BIOS hardware.. but how you write ISO to media matters here.

Comment: I did try acpi=off. boot got stuck at the running command screen when I edited the grub with 'e' and ctrl+x. I tried Ubuntu Desktop ISO. I didn't know initially they supported all those kernels. I tested 6.1,6.2,6.4, 6.5, 6.6 & 6.7.2. 6.1 got stuck and rest others gave 'panic error init killed'. Tried all of these after I installed 20.04 desktop, upgraded it to 22.04 LTS Desktop and installed them through mainline. I installed 23.10 desktop after modifying /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades to normal from lts, AND also through bootable usb drive. Created / as root and not /root. My bad.

Comment: Have you tried the BIOS detour workaround: https://askubuntu.com/q/1443856/1004020 ?

Comment: For both 22.04 LTS & 23.10 Desktop version, I have tried creating bootable drive from their ISO and installing that. They didn't work. 22.04 LTS only works when upgrading from 20.04 LTS keeping the kernel same to 5.15

Comment: @Daniel, I have not tried this. I am in the process of reinstalling 20.04 LTS and I will upgrade it to 22.04 LTS again and try that after updating the kernel too.

Comment: @Daniel: Tried the workaround mentioned in the thread with kernel 6.1.76, didn't work for me.

Comment: Meteor Lake Core Ultra may be a bit too new for the kernels you mention. Wait for Ubuntu 24.04, which should ship in April with kernel 6.8.

Comment: That's what I think, but then I see Phoronix showing up the meteor lake benchmarks on ubuntu and over the news that kernels 6.1 onwards have been getting the support added by Intel for meteor lake, I seem to think that I am missing something. Maybe my understanding is wrong. When I installed Kubuntu through virtualbox, I do see a warning everything I start the session that graphics is not supported, but considering my system hangs as the acpi checks and mounting file systems, the problem should be the laptop interfaces and not the processor itself? Can't differentiate between all these things.

Comment: Virtualbox hides the host graphics card and gives the guest a virtual graphics card. It is not related to this problem. Furthermore, acpi and mounting is much earlier than the graphical session